# Using \newcommand with \write\@auxout inside

Tags: write

I have read some related posts but still cannot resolve the problem with

```
     \newcommand{\myLabel}[2]{\makeatletter\write\@auxout{\string\newlabel{#1}{{#2}{\thepage}}}\makeatother}
```

I would like to write a line to .aux that will be later read as a label.  When executed on page 11 in subsection 3.1,

```
    \myLabel{Rings}{\thesubsection.2}
```

would write the line

```
    \newlabel{Rings}{{3.1.2}{11}}
```

I am unable to make this work.  Could you kindly explain what I do wrong and perhaps correct the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's actually easier (and better) to just use the `\label`-`\ref` system. It's easier because you don't have to worry about how to write out to the `.aux`, and it's better because it writes out to the `.aux` at the right time so the page references are correct. Here's how to do it:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myLabel}[2]{%
  \def\@currentlabel{#2}% Update label
  \label{#1}}% Mark label
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\myLabel{abc}{def}\ref{abc} \par

\section{Lord}
\subsection{of the}
\subsubsection{Rings}
\myLabel{Rings}{\thesubsubsection.2}\ref{Rings}

\end{document}
```

Note that the `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` pair has to be outside the macro definition. And updating `\@currentlabel` is the only thing needed to correctly establish the reference. The `.aux` file for the above MWE contains:

```
\relax 
\newlabel{abc}{{def}{1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}Lord}{1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.1}of the}{1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {1.1.1}Rings}{1}}
\newlabel{Rings}{{1.1.1.2}{1}}
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you so very much for your answer --- and so quick at that.  I just tried you solution, and it solved the problem perfectly.  I have also learned something new about the \label command and cannot thank you enough for all the above.