# Is there any way to extract the values stored in newlabel

Tags: labels

Context: I want to store values in the aux file to use them earlier in the file on the next run, rather than creating my own solution I want to use labels (as suggest by [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/186484/35735)).

Problem: Whenever a label is defined it creates something like this

```
\newlabel{customLabel}{{MyValue}{24}{}{Doc-Start}{}}
```

I want to be able to extract those values.  `\ref` does not work as its output is not just the value but some complex latex string.

Comment: `\getrefnumber{customLabel}` from package `refcount` -- it is expandable, `\ref` isn't.

Comment: That worked for my current problem, is there any reason why you will not post this as an answer?

Comment: I was writing an answer ;-)

Comment: I've added an answer, with another way of writing the label -- this is not shown by you, so I assumed some approach

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `refcount` and `\getrefnumber` it is possible to extract label values in an expandable way.

`\getrefnumber{foo}` will provide whatever is stored as `label` value, this might be a number but it is not restricted to numbers. (It can be 'anything')

The label value must be stored as second argument of `\newlabel`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{mylabelcounter}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\labelText}[2]{%
  \refstepcounter{mylabelcounter}%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{%
    \string\newlabel{#1}{{#2}{\thepage}{{\unexpanded{#2}}}{mylabelcounter.\number\value{mylabelcounter}}{}}
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\labelText{customLabel}{100}

\labelText{otherLabel}{24}

\ifnum\getrefnumber{otherLabel} < 25 
Hooray!!!
\else
Sorry!!!!
\fi


\ifnum\getrefnumber{customLabel} < 25 
Hooray!!!
\else
Sorry!!!!
\fi

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I used \def\@currentlabel{#2}\label{#1} to save the label but the net result is the same.